# Halberd - ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, linux, syntax-error

I am trying to install the w3af framework, I had some inconveniences as any installation that must be configured several things, I am stuck in the part where you install halberd (halberd-0.2.4.tar.gz):

Collecting halberd==0.2.4
  Downloading halberd-0.2.4.tar.gz (214 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 214 kB 1.8 MB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yl9osjq5/halberd/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yl9osjq5/halberd/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-yl9osjq5/halberd/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-yl9osjq5/halberd/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yl9osjq5/halberd/setup.py", line 72
        print "Running tests found in '%s'..." % module
                                             ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Running tests found in '%s'..." % module)?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I already tried to download the file and install it from pypi.org (https://pypi.org/project/halberd/) and I got the same error, how can I fix it?

Comment: It seems it is related to some incompatibilities. It is understood from the *parentheses problem* in *SyntaxError* that the installation need to be executed on python version 2, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

The `halberd` library on Pypi has not been updated since 2010 - it is unmaintained, and incompatible with modern python versions. There is a `halberd` project on Github, but that was also not updated since 2017.

The `w3af` project itself has many dependencies on unmaintained libraries, was developed for `python2` (which is no longer supported), and has not been updated by its maintainer in a couple of years.

If you are interested in using the framework still, you can check out the `w4af` project on Github, which includes the same functionality, but has been ported to `python3`, and all dependencies have also been updated to versions that work with `python3`.